# Чем отличается системный вызов от (программного) прерывания?

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Вызвать прерывание можно оператором int в ассемблере, при этом будет передано управление коду в ячейке с указанным номером из таблицы прерываний. При этом в linux возможен вызов прерывания intx80, именуемого syscall. Со стороны программиста это будет выглядеть как вызов библиотечной функции, которая, тем не менее, будет обработана в пространстве ядра. Так в чём разница между системным вызовом и софтверным прерыванием, если первый всё также вызывается через intx80?

Comment: Никакой разницы. С точки зрения процессора и то и другое - прерывание (как вы его назвали софтварное). Отдельное название только для того что бы сразу понимать, что происходит вызов функции ядра.

Comment: С другой стороны под рабочей ОС с точки зрения пользовательского кода никаких других прерываний не существует. Вызывать больше нечего. Кроме того на некоторых процессорах системы софтварных прерываний и отдельной инструкции подобной int может не быть и там syscall будет реализован по другому. А на других процессорах для вызова ядра вообще служит специализированная инструкция "вызов ядра". Однако его продолжат называть системным вызовом, что бы подчеркнуть что это не обычный библиотечный вызов

Comment: @Mike вы говорите пол рабочей ос никаких других прерываний не существует, однако нам же ничего не мешает написать и собрать ассемблерных код, который вызовет условно int21. И ос такую программу запустит, и она вполне себе отработает, просто управление будет передано коду из таблицы прерываний. Кстати, правильно ли я понимаю, что в этой таблице может быть помещена ссылка на любой пользовательский код?

Comment: Да, вы можете вызвать int 21h, на этом ваша программа аварийно завершится ввиду того, что ядро linux не предоставляет ни на каких прерываний кроме 80h. Все современные ОС работают в защищенном режиме процессора. Ядро не разрешает пользовательским программам ни читать ни писать что либо в таблице прерываний. Соответственно пользовательский код не сможет никуда поместить ссылку ни на какой код (если конечно вы специально для этого не напишите в ядре собственный системный вызов, который это сделает). Во времена ОС реального режима (DOS) программы использовали свои обработчики прерываний

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле это разные, несравнимые, вещи. По определениям википедии:

- *Системный вызов* — обращение прикладной программы к ядру операционной системы для выполнения какой-либо операции.
- *Прерывание* — сигнал от программного или аппаратного обеспечения, сообщающий процессору о наступлении какого-либо события, требующего немедленного внимания.
- *Программные прерывания* (в русской терминологии) — прерывания, которые инициируются исполнением специальной инструкции в коде программы.

Т.е. *системный вызов* — это абстракция ОС, в которой есть разделение на пространство пользователя и пространство ядра, а *программное прерывание* — это механизм взаимодействия программного кода с процессором.

Действительно, зачастую *системные вызовы* реализуются с помощью *программных прерываний*, но это не обязательно так, например, на amd64 поддерживается по меньшей мере 3 способа:

- инструкция `syscall` — основной способ, появился появился только на архитектуре amd64, в режиме совместимости x86 есть не на всех процессорах (только на процессорах amd), самый быстрый из перечисленных.
- инструкция `sysenter` — аналогичная старая инструкция, появилась во времена Pentium 2, основной способ при сборке под архитектуру i686.
- собственно `int 80h` — считается устаревшим (*legacy*) способом, относительно медленный, время на переключение контекста примерно вдвое дольше, чем с помощью `syscall`.